# Unable to manipulate via getElementById for AJAXed dropdown lists

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html, ajax

I am using this to pull dropdown lists:

```
function showRecords(str,column,nextDiv) {
  if (str== null) {
    document.getElementById(nextDiv).innerHTML="----------------------------------------";
    return;
  }
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
    // code for IE6, IE5
    var xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
      document.getElementById(nextDiv).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","getRecords.php?"+column+"="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

The page is loading fine, however, when you look at the source info, there is nothing there from AJAX, therefore I cannot manipulate any of the values of the dropdown lists via `getElementById`, is this normal?

---

### Clarification

The actual ID itself is on the main page, but all the options are being imported from another page. I am unable to use this code in particular:

```
<?php echo "document.getElementById('province').value =\"Abim\";";?>
```

Because these countries don't exist on this page, they are imported values, not only that, but the only thing on the page is this...

```
<option value = >--------------------</option>
<option value="Abim">Abim</option>
<option value="Adjumani">Adjumani</option>
<option value="Amolatar">Amolatar</option>
<option value="Amuria">Amuria</option>
... etc
```

Which is all being inserted here

```
<select name =province class=dropdown id=province></select>
```

by virtue of the id.

---

### Solution

Pass another variable through the AJAX function: oldVal ($_REQUESTed Value)

```
...
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById(nextDiv).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        ---------> document.getElementById(nextDiv).value = oldVal;
    }
}
```

Comment: Both, it is displaying on the DOM inspector, but not on the source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do anything useful with the `province` element until it has been populated by your AJAX call. You have to move this bit of JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('country').value = "Uganda";
```

into your AJAX callback:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById(nextDiv).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        document.getElementById('country').value = "Uganda";
    }
};
```

Or something along those lines. Your comment to nnnnnn is talking about a country list but your updated question is talking about a province list so I'm not sure which one is your problem; however, I'm pretty sure that the underlying problem is that you are setting the value of a `<select>` before you have populated that `<select>` with an AJAX call and the solution is to set the value in the AJAX callback after updating the DOM with the HTML from your AJAX call.

Comment: I see exactly what you are saying, I am fiddling with it right now. Thank you.

Comment: The problem is a mixture of the two, There are regions, countries and province, once $_POST['province'] is set, then I am having it generate the proper drop down list for countries, however, it is having it select that value i.e. Uganda which is hard. Same thing for country to region.

Comment: I just passed another variable... I will post the final function at the top.

Comment: Thank you so much :) My interface works really smoothly now :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use View/Source it will normally only show you the source for the page at the time it first loaded, i.e., it will not include items created programatically later. If you think about it that is actually *good*, because it lets you see how the page starts out. However, you should still be able to manipulate elements created programatically, including elements cretaed from an AJAX return. Having said that, there are more advanced browser-based debugging tools than just View/Source.

If you want to use `getElementById()` make sure your server-side code returns an id attribute for the elements in question. If you're having problems getting that to work it might help us if you posted some of your server-side code.

Comment: THE actual ID itself is on the main page, but all the options are being imported from another page. I am unable to use this code in particular: <?php echo "document.getElementById('country').value =\"Uganda\";";?> because Uganda doesn't exist on this page, it is an imported value.